# Change button text Stripe Checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

is it possible to change button text in the strip checkout page?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwtQ6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to partially customize the Checkout button text, but it depends on which [mode](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-mode) of Checkout you're using:

- In Checkout's `subscription` mode the button text is fixed to `Subscribe`.
- If in `subscription` mode and the subscription has a trial the text is fixed to `Start trial` unless there is also a setup fee in which case it will be `Pay {amount} and start trial`.
- In `setup` mode the button text is also fixed, and will equal `Save card`.

In `payment` mode the button text depends on the [submit_type](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-submit_type), for which there are three options:

- `pay`: the submit button text will be `Pay`.
- `donate`: the submit button text will be `Donate`.
- `book`: the submit button text will be `Book for`.

It's not currently possible to enter in a custom string or customize the text beyond these options.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm using trial periods on subscriptions and what i want to change is the text in the pay button '' Pay {Price} and start trial ''.
Is it possible to change 'Trial' or remove it completely from pay button?
[IMAGE-LINK](https://ibb.co/7R01JtM)

Comment: Forgot about trials! I updated the answer accordingly. And no, basically in subscription mode you can't customize the text at this time unfortunately.

Comment: It's a shame we can't customize `pay_button` in subscription mode. I'm sending my users for stripe checkout with a trial period, but I'd like the CTA to state "Subscribe", and not "Start trial".